Google apps script missing
I have 2 scripts that I have published on 2 different Google Site since the old Google sites (more than 10 years ago). Every year I updated them, change some code and staff. Since one week ago, as I have been informed, they stop working and the error is:
Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
Make sure that you have the correct URL and the file exists.
I try to find them in the script.google.com in My Projects, and they are also missing there. I have all my other projects there, only this 2 scripts are missing.
Can somebody help me where to locate them, I don't have backup of them.

This is not a programming question you need Google Support in this case.

Have you tried the trash?

Welcome to stackoverflow. I would like to confirm if aside from using google products like for example appscript. Do you have Admin Console subscription? If there is you might  able to recover it from the Google Vault. Ask your administrator with in your company about that information.

Hi Savo, check this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364657532#comment17

This seems to be a known issue as commented by @jpp here.
Add +1 by clicking the +1 on  the top of the page to let Google developers increase  it's priority.
Some suggested solutions:

Comment #17:


Step 1: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?sjid=14541840185849280270-NC
Step 2:  In the bottom you should see a button" Request File Recovery" leading to https://support.google.com/drive?p=file_recovery. This button is not appearing to me for a different login ID, I am not sure why.
Step 3: It will login again. You add the details.
Step 4: It will create a case and send you an email.
Within 6 minutes I got another email saying all files are restored. All my projects were back.
The trick is to get that "Request File Recovery" Button


Comment#26 as suggested by savo-efremovski here:


From the Admin Panel, find the user and go into their profile. On the left side choose "Restore Data" and choose the time ranges. Worked within a minute. –
Savo Efremovski


Thanks for help. The solution here didn't fix the problem for me, the link don't appear to the Google Workspace users. But on the page from the link to the Google Issue tracker you provide I found a solution for me, here is the link to the comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364657532?pli=1#comment28
From the Admin Panel, find the user and go into their profile. On the left side choose "Restore Data" and choose the time ranges. Worked within a minute.

@SavoEfremovski Great. Added to the community answer.  Feel  free to edit, if needed
